# How to Fourier transform an Android camera image?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-camera, fft

This is a question I've been mulling over for a couple of evenings now, and I'm not really any closer to an answer. I'd like to take the Fourier transform of an image that's just been taken on a camera on an Android device. Now the way I see it, there are 3 options for doing this:

1. Transform the byte[] array which is returned from the camera, then change the result to an image which can be displayed. This seems the most direct method but I can't find any libraries which can transform byte arrays.
2. Convert the byte array to an int[] or other number array and run a transform from one of the mathematical libraries like JTransform. Then convert to an image from the number array.
3. Convert the camera image to a RenderedImage object and use the DFTDescriptor class in the Java Advanced Imaging library to perform the transform. Not sure how well this would run on phone processors AND the documentation for JAI isn't exactly the clearest...

Or have I missed some other glaringly obvious way that merits a **hit head with hand**?

I'd be really grateful if someone could shine some light on this. I seem to be going in circles with it!

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, how was you doing with your project? May I know some details about how to convert the byte array to double[] and how to convert the result back to an image? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you use Piotr Wendykier's [JTransform library](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) (as per your option 2). Amongst other possibilities it specifically supplies a 2D DFT transform, which should fit your requirement nicely.

Cheers,